# Selenium won't recognize credentials

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, credentials

I have seen familiar answered questions, basically what was told is that Selenium doesn't use the standard/basic Chrome instance but an empty one. However, what bothers me is the scenario as follows: after running the test/script where i, for example click the "remember me" button, enter the credentials , then log in , and log out right away, shouldn't the created instance of Chrome remember these credentials until i "driver.close" ? In my case the fields are empty. I'm a beginner, mby i misunderstood something? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by empty chrome? chromedriver uses usual chrome but in incognito mode which means anything you did outside the selenium runtime doesn't apply to your selenium runtime. In other words if you log in using chrome manually and then start your selenium test - it won't recognize you, you have to log in using selenium. Empty browser might have meant PhantomJS which doesn't have any ui and doesn't waste time for rendering.

But if I got your question right, you enter creds via selenium, click remember me, click login button and then log out and expect your creds to be entered? In this case they shouldn't. Remember me puts token or encrypted creds (in case of basic authorization) into browsers cookies so that your session keeps alive. It allows you not to log in after some time or after you close the tab or browser but in any case it doesn't fill fields for you. Only browsers have such option, not applications.

Comment: I might sound a bit silly because i'm a newbie in this topic but i don't really get it. Doesn't Selenium open a common browser just in incognito mode just as you stated? "chromedriver uses usual chrome but in incognito mode " if so , then why is it considered an app ? In addition i don't close the driver aka driver.quit, i just log out from the account. I enter the credentials through Selenium , i'm not opening Chrome manually and then starting any tests. I do everything through Selenium.

Comment: That's okay. We all started from zero one day. Applcation under test aka your web site manages cookies which are responsible for auth token. If you use Selenium to log in and then log out without driver.quit() you should stay on log in page with empty fields for creds.